# asp.net web api tracing - redirect to another listener

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net app hosted in iis. it works as web api rest service.
I write a log which is configured as:

```
<source ...>
  <listeners>
    <add ... />
  </listeners>
</source>
```

I added nuget for web api tracing and it prints ok in my visual studio. the tracing configured in webapiconfig.cs as:

```
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

I would like to redirect the output into the existing log..

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebApiTracer : ITraceWriter
{
    public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, System.Web.Http.Tracing.TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
    {
        TraceRecord rec = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
        traceAction(rec);
        WriteTrace(rec);
    }

    protected void WriteTrace(TraceRecord rec)
    {
        var message = string.Format("WebApi. {0};{1};{2};{3};{4}",
            rec.Category, rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message, rec.Exception);

        myLog.Write(message);
    }
}
```